# opengl shadows mistake

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw shadows in opengl following along with the recipe in the red book http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name15

To start off simply, I will place the light that casts shadows at the origin.

I place the camera at x,y,z = 0,1,0 looking 'down' along the -ve y axis.

I draw a square 0.1 by 0.1 at y = 0.1

```
float mx,pz,elevation;
mx = pz = elevation = 0.1;
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glVertex3f( mx, elevation, pz);
glVertex3f( mx, elevation, pz+0.1);
glVertex3f( mx+0.1, elevation, pz+0.1);
glVertex3f( mx+0.1, elevation, pz);
glEnd();
```

Which shows up as expected:

[image]

Now I define a 'ground plane' at y = 0.5 (i.e. approx half way between the square and the camera.  According to the recipe in the red book ( if I understand it right ) the shadow matrix should be:

```
// shadow matrix
GLfloat shadow[] = { 
    0.5,0,0,0,
    0, 0.5,0,0,
    0,0, 0.5,0,
    0,1,0,0 };
```

So I add

```
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glMultMatrixf( shadow );
```

I am expecting to see the square's shadow on the ground plane - a slightly larger square.  Instead I get a perfect blank.

What's my mistake?

( I have tried every combination of flipping the signs on the values of the shadow matrix and the elevation of the rendered square.  All give me blank. )

( I have also tried replacing the shadow matrix with the identity matrix - the original square reappears.  So this seems to rule out a stupid coding error - there is something wrong with the shadow matrix. )

Maybe some algebra will help?

An arbitrary ground plane:

a . x + b . y + c . y + d = 0

The vector from any light to any vertex

```
x = lx + m . ( vx - lx )
y = ly + m . ( vy - ly )
z = lz + m . ( vz - lz )
```

Solving for m

m = - ( a . lx + b . ly + c . lz  + d ) / ( a . vx - a . lx + b . vy - b . ly + c . vz - c . lx )

Now place the light at the origin

```
m = -d / ( a . vx + b . vy + c . vz )

x = m . vx
y = m . vy
z = m . vz
```

Now place the ground plane at y = 0.5

```
m = 0.5 / vy

x = 0.5 . vx / vy
y = 0.5
z = 0.5 . vz / vy
```

This should be the point at which the shadow of vertex v hits the ground.  Indeed calculating these points manually and plugging them into opengl gives the expected display!

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it!

The opengl red book at http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter14.html#name15 states that the shadow matrix is

{-d,0,0,0, 0,-d,0,0, 0,0,-d,0, a,b,c,0 }

This does not work.

However, this does:

{-d,0,0,a, 0,-d,0,b, 0,0,-d,c, 0,0,0,0 }